# Logout link with Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

According with the official example ([Secure Web Content](http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/)), I have to use a form and a button with the aim to perform a logout with Spring Security.
Is there a way to use a link with Thymeleaf instead of a button?

Comment: Style the button as a link. It needs, for security reasons, to be a POST instead of a GET request. You can also configure the logout filter to accept get requests but that is less secure.

Comment: Also see http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to use a form for log out. If you really want a link, you can use JavaScript to have the link perform a POST on a hidden form.

```
<a href="javascript: document.logoutForm.submit()" role="menuitem"> Logout</a>

   <form name="logoutForm" th:action="@{/logout}" method="post" th:hidden="true">
      <input hidden type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
   </form>
```

Comment: Note that I needed to change the 'hidden' attribute of the 'input' element to 'hidden="true"'

Answer (score 28):

I have successfully used `<a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>`

The relevant Spring Security config I used was

```
 http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

Comment: This didn't work for me as <a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a> generated get request

Comment: Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RC2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/LogoutConfigurer.html#logoutUrl%28java.lang.String%29) for the configuration, and then just change the html/thymeleaf anchor to a form

Answer (score 18):

With respect to the context of this question I think vdenotaris wants a link not a submit button for the log out functionality. well I think what you can do is create a hyperlink like this :

```
<a href="#" th:href="@{/logout}">Log Out</a>
```

and now create a controller with below mapping :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout";
}
```

Comment: this block of code is actually working. a little explanation on how it is working might help other viewers.

Answer (score 10):

The solution (deprecated!) is:

```
       .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
```

It is recommended to use POST instead of a GET request for security, as mentioned above.

Comment: This worked for me. need to find out the way to do it in post

Comment: @vdenotaris Can you please explain why it is DEPRECATED? And should I use it or not?

Comment: @Partho63 Because this implementation handles the logout process via HTTP GET instead of POST, as stated in my answer. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-logout

Answer (score 8):

Thats the right answer.

```
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit">POST LOGOUT</input>
</form>
```

Comment: if "Is there a way to use a link with Thymeleaf instead of a button?" is the question, how is using a button the right answer?

Answer (score 4):

"In order to help protect against CSRF attacks, by default, Spring Security Xml Configuration log out requires:

- the HTTP method must be a POST
- the CSRF token must be added to the
  request. You can access it on the ServletRequest using the attribute
  _csrf as illustrated above."

[Hello Spring Security Xml Config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//helloworld-xml.html)

```
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" /> 
    <input type="submit">LOGOUT</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following snippet of code in your file:

```
  <!--In case of csrf enabled post logout is working -->

  <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="POST LOGOUT"></input>
  </form>
```

Comment: Using thymeleaf