# Logout link does not redirect with Spring Security and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I use `Spring Security` and `Thymeleaf` to provide logout feature, based on answers from [Logout link with Spring and Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557741/logout-link-with-spring-and-thymeleaf):

```
<form class="pull-xs-right" method="post"
    th:action="@{/logout}"
>
    <button class="nav-item nav-link" type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

With `Spring Security` config:

```
http
    .formLogin()
    .successHandler(
        new DifferentRoleBasedStartingURLsAuthenticationSuccessHandler()
    )
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/jobs/**").authenticated()
    .antMatchers("/interviews/**").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
;
```

And it worked almost OK - request was send, it was POST to `/hire-platform/logout` (where `hire-platform` is deploy URL of my project). But it also should redirect to `/` I think, and nothing happened. Logout was correct I think, because if I clicked logout button again I got page with `403` status, or if I refreshed page with F5 it redirected me to `/`. But it should did redirect right after click, and it didn't. I ended up with a by-pass solution, which was create my own `logoutSuccessHandler`:

```
public final class RedirectToPageLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {
    private final String url;

    public RedirectToPageLogoutSuccessHandler(final String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, final HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, final Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/hire-platform" + url);
    }
}
```

But this is bad solution, unnecessarily complicated I think (I am pretty sure it should be simpler), and it has hard-coded `/hire-platform` string. Is something wrong with my code, which I can not see, which causes after POST to `logout` redirection not occurs? I would be very grateful if anybody will help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it because of missing csrf token?