# Logout link with Spring and Thymeleaf; post error

Tags: java, spring

Following Problem:

I created a simple logout with Spring:

```
    <form th:action="@{/logout-custom}" method="POST" name="logoutForm" 
    id="logout">
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
```

Security:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/cont/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .and()

            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-success", true)
            .failureUrl("/failLogin.html")
            .permitAll()

            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()

        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable();
}
```

Controller:

```
//Logout
@RequestMapping(value="/logout-custom", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return new RedirectView("/loginForm.html");
}   
// redirecting to login Page
```

Dependencies:

```
               <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I click the logout button it shows a "Request method 'POST' not supported" Error.

With method GET it just added a "?" sign behind my url not showing an error nor redirecting.
I removed everything from my html, except the form, cause it seems some scripts blocked the whole thing (That's a later problem).
I also tried to remove the controller and just use logout().logoutUrl().logoutSuccessUrl() but that didn't work too.

Comment: I know. I think this doesn't have to point to the same path as the controller and the logout form. Does it?
I just tried to point all 3 to logout-custom. Same error..

Comment: whats the exact exception in log, root cause ? this message could belong to the last exception of stacktrace.

Comment: @benjaminc The stacktrace is:

Request method 'POST' not supported 
[nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: Can you post your spring pom dependencies?

Comment: @CrazySabbath Sure.

Comment: POST method is supported when CSRF is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SecurityContextLogoutHandler`is added by default so you don't need to implement a custom logout for it.

If you want to add other `LogoutHandler` you can do it in your configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/cont/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .and()

            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/login-success", true)
            .failureUrl("/failLogin.html")
            .permitAll()

            .and()
            .logout().logoutUrl("/logout-custom")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .addLogoutHandler(new CustomLogoutHandler())
            .permitAll()

        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable();
}
```

The `logoutSuccessUrl("/login")` will redirect the user to the login after a successful logout.

UPDATE:
Additionally removing the th: and using plain HTML does the trick.

Comment: I changed it as u wrote, but without the CustomLogoutHandler.
I changed my url at form to /logout but it still doen't work..

Comment: @temp the action and the configured logout url must match so I updated my answer

Comment: I just did as the user a comment below suggested. And even that simple solution didn't work. I guess there might be something wrong with my form.. you got an idea why?

Comment: @temp can you try using a link instead of the form <a href="/logout">logout</a>

Comment: Oh wow, that finally worked!
And I also are logged out.

Maybe there was an error with thymeleaf?
Cause as I tried: <a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a> instead of just a normal link, it didn't work.

EDIT: And even the form works after removing thymeleaf!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used spring with thymeleaf, but I think RedirectView has to point to a url. I tried your example myself, and it indeed did not work. Some slight changes made it work however:

Add url to login if it does not already exist in your controller:

```
@GetMapping("/loginForm")
public String loginForm() {
    return "loginForm";
}
```

Change your redirecView:

```
return new RedirectView("/loginForm");
```

And here's resources structure:

```
resources
  -> templates
    -> loginForm.html
    -> logout.html
```

Comment: okay, thanks. But I don't have a logout.html

I am loging out on home.html, which is one folder above.

Comment: And changing the RedirectView("/login-success") (That's my redirect for login)
didn't work for me.

Comment: logout.html does not matter, it's just an example, since I didn't have your .html file which included logout form.

Answer (score 0):

Why using   `.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()`

At the same time, using `@RequestMapping(value="/logout-custom", method = RequestMethod.POST)`, they should be the same URL

Or just make it simple

```
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
         <button type="submit">Sign Out</button>        
 </form>
```

And at the security configuration use.

```
   .logout().permitAll();
```

The logout functionality is already there by default.

Comment: When i do it like you say, there's no specified logout page?

Comment: I changed it as u said, but it still didn't work.
I also tried to name the URL at my controller and my form the same, but that didn't changed anything too.

Comment: Do you mean, the log out happens and you need to display the page after logout? or the logout is not happening at all?

Comment: I guess the logout isn't happening at all. It just shows the POST error.

Comment: Try my solution and set  .logoutSuccessUrl("/login"); it will refer for example to the login page

Comment: So, I commented out the controller. Changed the form as urs and set the logoutSuccessUrl. But still get the error.

The url at the form "/logout" - what's the purpose of that?

Comment: I don't know what the error you are facing? the logout is simply call the spring security logout controller, and you just need to specify the success page in case of logout

The /logout should work directly without any configuration and it by default will forward to the root /

Comment: Try to see this link, it may help you as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557741/logout-link-with-spring-and-thymeleaf

Comment: I think there must be something wrong with my form, cause I get the error just before the logout...

Comment: Check the generated source code of the html in this case

Comment: Well, the source code is exactly the same as in my file... God, I hate this error. :D

Comment: Do you mean Thymeleaf is not rendering? .. you are wasting our time man

Comment: Sry, I didn't mean to do that. I am just new to spring and thymeleaf. 
But yea, the error must be at thymeleaf. I solved the problem like Tom wrote it, by just using a link tag.